# How Make close the current tab after the code executed

Tags: javascript

Hi Hello I Have a Php page And i liked this current tab close after execute all the code in that page.
Some One Know If That Is Possible And How Please.
i have try like this but the current tab its not close
here its my code

```html
<?php
session_start();
include_once 'dbconnect.php';

if(!isset($_SESSION['user']))
{
 header("Location: index.php");
}

$res=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id=".$_SESSION['user']);
$userRow=mysql_fetch_array($res);
// Retrieve data from database 
$result=mysql_query($sql);
//$sql = mysql_query("UPDATE `users` SET points=`points`+5 WHERE user_id='".$_SESSION['user']."'");
$user_id = mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['user']);
$sql = mysql_query("UPDATE `users` SET user_points = user_points +'100' WHERE user_id = " . $_SESSION['user']);

if(isset($_POST['ok']))
{


}
// close MySQL connection 
mysql_close();
echo "<script>window.close();</script>";
?>
```

Comment: This is hardly a question. Have you done anything so far?  Show us, don't let us guess

Comment: i have try multiple times but now i know way its not worked because i worked in local host